# Elasticsearch: How to filter aggregation result of top hits

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-7

I want to filter my aggregation result using bucket_selector, but I want to use it over top_hits result. Is it possible?

```html
GET new-transactions-2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_name": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "items"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "products": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "items.product_id",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_amount": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "items.amount"
              }
            },
            "bucketSelector1": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "x" : "sum_amount"
                },
                "script": "params.x > 40000"
              }
            },
            "additionalFields": {
              "top_hits": {
                "_source": {"includes": ["items.amount", "items.title"]}, 
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the imaginary code that I want to achieve.

```html
"bucketSelector2": {
  "bucket_selector": {
    "buckets_path": {
      "x" : "additionalFields"
    },
    "script": "params.additionalFields.items.title.contains('Ayam')"
  }
}
```

I got the warning when run this request. It's said that

> buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [InternalTopHits] at aggregation [additionalFields]

I'm curious if there is another way to achieve this kind of filter, please help..